# PowerShell helpfiles not displaying correctly

Tags: powershell

Tested in PowerShell 4.0, 5.0 on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012:

```
clear
help *-wmiobject*
```

or

```
cls
man *-job*
```

The help file does not display results correctly after clearing screen. Re-run the command and it works as expected.

```
Get-Help is unaffected.
```

What is the reason for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A funny bug. The reason (apparently) is that the progress bar for "Searching for help" is updated after Powershell displays the results of `help()` call, effectively clearing the 8 rows from row #2 to #9 from the top. The workaround is store the result in a temporary variable.

```
$temp=help *-wmiobject; $temp
```

This ensures that the function has exited before displaying stuff, thus the progress bar will already be removed from the window.

UPDATE: The bug isn't present if you do not include the asterisks in the argument to `help`. Therefore, the bug might arise because the displaying is done in the "Process" part of `help()`, and the code that clears the progress bar is located in the "End" part of the function.

Comment: :) try `cls;help param;help param` to see what's cleared after the progress bar disappears:)

Comment: @JosefZ Okay, 5 lines from #3 to #7. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to reproduce this on a 64-bit Windows 8.1 machine on both PowerShell consoles (32/64-bit)

Short version is it's to do with the [`more.com` DOS command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DOS_commands#MORE) which is used by `man` and `help` but not `Get-Help`.

**Get-Help, help, man: what's the difference?**
Better explained by Don Jones*, and [this $Script Fanatic blog post](https://scriptolog.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/help-vs-get-help.html):

[image: differences explained]

**more**
Running `(Get-ChildItem function:\help).definition` as described in the blog post, you will see this at the bottom:

```
Get-Help @PSBoundParameters | more
```

`help` basically binds the parameters to `Get-Help` Cmdlet and pipes to `more`. So as well as what you have posted, you will have the same issue if you use:

```
clear
Get-Help *et-WmiObjec* | more # doesn't work
```

I believe `Get-Help` uses `Out-Host` by default to output information (citation needed). Using `Write-Output` also works.

```
clear
help *-wmiobject* | Out-Host # works

clear
man *-wmiobject* | Out-Host # works
```

Lastly, this appears to be an issue when multiple results are returned by `man`/`help`.

```
clear
man get-WmiObject # works
```

I recommend checking out the documentation and help functions to investigate this. From the results of `(Get-ChildItem function:\more).definition`, I suspect it's to do with handling arrays/object vs string but this is behind the scope of my knowledge.

```
param([string[]]$paths)

$OutputEncoding = [System.Console]::OutputEncoding

if($paths)
{
    foreach ($file in $paths)
    {
        Get-Content $file | more.com
    }
}
else
{
    $input | more.com
}
```

*PowerShell Month of Lunches, 2nd Ed, pg 23